# Could bayesian network input data be probability?

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification, bayesian, bayesian-networks

For example:

```
 A     B     C     D     result
 0.7   0.6   0.5   0.9    good
 0.3   0.2   0.1   0.3    bad
 0.5   0.0   0.2   0.9    good
.............
```

Is it possible to use bayesian network to analyse it, then every time when get a data like [0.7,0.3,0.6,0.6]. The user could get a probability of the chance that it might be good or bad ?

Comment: `Is it possible to use bayesian network to analyse it` <- Yes

Comment: As I saw before, most of examples are based on the Boolean values.  Would you mind talk about more details as a hint ? @inspectorG4dget

Comment: If your probabilistic input simply captures the notion that the input is present with that probability, I would expect that you have basically captured two variables in one, in the input (and therefore, training). Thus, you'd have to slightly tweak the training formula to capture this idea. But aside from that, you can leave the network unchanged

Comment: For example, you could assume the result is sampled from a Bernoulli random variable and its probability is a weighted average of the probabilities A, B, C, and D. This could be done by putting a Dirichlet prior on the weights and computing the posterior on thee weights given the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just saw your question few minutes ago. As I learnt from college, Bayesian linear regression can be defined as an approach to linear regression in which the statistical analysis is undertaken within the context of Bayesian inference.

And according to the model of bayesian regression, the result can be analysid through numberic values, and turn out to be a boolean result.

Here is the model [image]
Hope this can help you. It's been a long time since I learnt that. :)